# Missing element to complete a palindrome by python

Tags: set, compare, missing-data, palindrome

I don't know how to do it USING PYTHON.

But the program must print the missing letter in the given palindrome.

INPUT should be:
input_string="abcdeedba"

OUTPUT should be:
c

I guess we can solve this using set difference or split it into two halves and compare them

Answer (score 0):

I have tried solving this problem by splitting the palindrome string into two halves and comparing them. Hope this helps!

```
def find_missing_element(input_string):
    length = len(input_string)
    
    # Check if the string length is even or odd, if the length is odd, skip the middle character
    if length % 2 == 0:
        first_half = input_string[:(length // 2)]
        second_half = input_string[(length // 2):]
    else:
        first_half = input_string[:(length // 2)]
        second_half = input_string[((length // 2) + 1):]
    
    # Reverse the second half of string
    second_half = second_half[::-1]
    
    # Now compare the two halves
    for i in range(len(first_half)):
        if first_half[i] != second_half[i]:
            return first_half[i]
    # If no missing element is found 
    return None  

# Take input
input_string = input("Enter a palindrome string: ")
missing_element = find_missing_element(input_string)
if missing_element:
    print(missing_element)
else:
    print("No missing element found")
```